# Kernel Panic after using gparted on root and then running e2fsck on root partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, gparted

I was resizing my root partition and then gparted couldn't complete operations. Thereafter running the e2fsck -y on /dev/sda6(root), the computer on booting shows that the "kernel panic-attempting to kill init" error. I tried to go with this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867591/how-to-solve-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-without-er).

However, i had no config file in /etc/selinux and it seems missing. I don't want to reinstall. Please help. I tried booting with older kernel versions but that too ends up with the same error. Windows boots nice and good. Also, now i am unable to mount the root drive using nautilus on a bootable disk